# Erro ao tentar popular um List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou tentando criar uma tabela com union, eu fiz uma classe para popular na `ViewModel`, desta forma:

```
  public class ListVencimentos {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public int? TipoDocumentoId { get; set; }
    public Models.TipoDocumento TipoDocumento { get; set; }
    public float Valor { get; set; }
    public float JaPago { get; set; }
    public float Saldo { get; set; }
    public float Desconto { get; set; } 
    public float Mora { get; set; } 
    public float Multa { get; set; }
    public float Outros { get; set; }
    public float Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataPagamento { get; set; }
    public int? DiasAtraso { get; set; }
}
```

Chamando assim `public IEnumerable<ListVencimentos> ListVencimentos { get; set; }`

E para fazer os `selects` ficou assim, que está puxando corretamente:

```
 var un = db.ContasPagar.Include(c => c.ContasPagarP).Where(c => c.FornecedorId == id).Select(c => new
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Data = c.Data,
                TipoDocumentoId = c.TipoDocumentoId,
                Valor = c.Valor,
                JaPago = c.JaPago,
                Saldo = c.Saldo,
                Desconto = c.Desconto,
                Mora = c.Mora,
                Multa = c.Multa,
                Outros = c.Outros,
                Total = c.Total,
                DataPagamento = c.DataPagamento,
                DiasAtraso = c.DiasAtraso

            }).ToList()
            .Union(db.FaturaContasPagar.Include(r => r.FaturaContasPagarP).Where(r => r.FornecedorId == id).Select(r => new
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                Data = r.Data,
                TipoDocumentoId = r.TipoDocumentoId,
                Valor = r.Valor,
                JaPago = r.JaPago,
                Saldo = r.Saldo,
                Desconto = r.Desconto,
                Mora = r.Mora,
                Multa = r.Multa,
                Outros = r.Outros,
                Total = r.Total,
                DataPagamento = r.DataPagamento,
                DiasAtraso = r.DiasAtraso
            }).ToList());
```

Só que quando eu vou popular o `ListVencimentos`, ele está me retornando o seguinte erro.

> Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>" em "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable". Existe uma conversão explícita (há uma conversão ausente?)

Como posso fazer, será que estou esquecendo de algum detalhe ?

**EDIT**

Estou tentando preencher dessa forma:

```
ListVencimentos = un.Select(r => new ListVencimentos { r.Id, r.Data, r.TipoDocumentoId, r.Valor, r.JaPago, r.Saldo, r.Desconto,
                    r.Mora, r.Multa, r.Outros, r.Total, r.DataPagamento })
```

E ele está retornando o erro:

> Não é possível inicializar o tipo "ListVencimentos" com um inicializador de coleta porque ele não implementa "System.Collections.IEnumerable"

Como posso carregar o resultado `un`, em uma `table` ? De toda forma que eu tento ele retorna algum tipo de erro de conversão.

Comment: Altere de tipo anônimo para o seu tipo no seu `.Select(s => new ListVencimentos { ... })`

Comment: Ele me retornou o seguinte erro. Não é possível inicializar o tipo "ListVencimentos" com um inicializador de coleta porque ele não implementa "System.Collections.IEnumerable" 
Eu mudei para `ListVencimentos = un.Select(r => new ListVencimentos { r.Id, r.Data, r.TipoDocumentoId, r.Valor, r.JaPago, r.Saldo, r.Desconto,
                        r.Mora, r.Multa, r.Outros, r.Total, r.DataPagamento })`

Comment: Você está tentando inicializar sua classe como uma lista? Exemplo: `ListVencimentos lista = un.Select(s => new ListVencimentos {...});` Se for isso não irá funcionar, pois sua classe não é uma coleção.

Comment: @PedroPaulo sim, na `ViewModel` eu declarei assim `public IEnumerable<ListVencimentos> ListVencimentos { get; set; }` e no `load` do editar está assim: `ListVencimentos= un.Select(r => new ListVencimentos { r.Id, r.Data, r.TipoDocumentoId, r.Valor, r.JaPago, r.Saldo, r.Desconto,
                        r.Mora, r.Multa, r.Outros, r.Total, r.DataPagamento }),`

Comment: Assim de cabeça sem analisar o código como um todo fica meio complicado, teria que dar uma analisada melhor, pois aparentemente seria isso mesmo... Vai acabar gerando flood nos comentários, caso queira cotinuar a discussão chama no chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie duas variáveis separadas para poder analisar melhor enquanto estiver depurando seu código.

Na primeira variável iremos armazenar a query com as contas a pagar. No `Select` iremos criar uma instância da sua classe `ListVencimentos`, fazendo as associações dos campos da query com a classe.

```
var contas = db.ContasPagar.Include(c => c.ContasPagarP).Where(c=> c.ContasPagarP.FornecedorId == id).Select(c => new ListVencimentos
{
    Id = c.Id,
    Data = c.Data,
    TipoDocumentoId = c.TipoDocumentoId,
    Valor = c.Valor,
    JaPago = c.JaPago,
    Saldo = c.Saldo,
    Desconto = c.Desconto,
    Mora = c.Mora,
    Multa = c.Multa,
    Outros = c.Outros,
    Total = c.Total,
    DataPagamento = c.DataPagamento,
    DiasAtraso = c.DiasAtraso
}).ToList();
```

Na segunda variável iremos armazenar a query com as faturas a pagar. No `Select` iremos criar uma instância da sua classe `ListVencimentos`, fazendo as associações dos campos da query com a classe.

```
var faturas = db.FaturaContasPagar.Include(c => c.FaturaContasPagarP).Where(c=> c.FaturaContasPagarP.FornecedorId == id).Select(c => new ListVencimentos
{
    Id = c.Id,
    Data = c.Data,
    TipoDocumentoId = c.TipoDocumentoId,
    Valor = c.Valor,
    JaPago = c.JaPago,
    Saldo = c.Saldo,
    Desconto = c.Desconto,
    Mora = c.Mora,
    Multa = c.Multa,
    Outros = c.Outros,
    Total = c.Total,
    DataPagamento = c.DataPagamento,
    DiasAtraso = c.DiasAtraso,
}).ToList();
```

Agora que possuímos todos os valores que precisamos, basta utilizar o método `Union` com o resultado das duas querys anteriores:

```
var union = contas.Union(faturas).ToList();
```

Espero ter ajudado!